# Aenetmail office 365 move message

Tags: c#, imap

I'm using AENetMail imap library with an office 365 account. I have a big problem, I can't move messages to another folder without duplicate it. I can move the message to the another folder, but I have to delete it from its original location (or delete the original flag).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (ImapClient ic = new ImapClient("imap server name", "username", "pass", ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 993,true))
        {
            ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX/Teszt");
            Lazy<MailMessage>[] messages = ic.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Unseen(), false);
            foreach (Lazy<MailMessage> message in messages)
            {
                MailMessage m = message.Value;
                ic.MoveMessage(m.Uid, "probamappa");
                ic.DeleteMessage(m.Uid);
            }

        }
}
```

How can I delete the message from the original folder?

Comment: ic.Expunge(); function solved the problem!